When writing a cover letter, how do I avoid repeating what is on a CV?
I am applying to a public health related job (my background is in epidemiology) and I have the experience that the job is asking for. I also have a CV and I know that in a CV we can write a list of achievements/responsibilities for jobs/roles.
My two questions are:

if I am applying for a job that is almost identical to a job I had, how do I talk about it in the cover letter without repeating the CV?

similar to question 1, how can I avoid repeating myself regarding this experience if I am asked to talk about it during an interview?



Some overlap is going to happen. Focus on why you are a GREAT fit for the company. The cover letter is something to help "pop" your CV to the keep list.

The cover letter should be short and sweat, saying just enough, to cause whomever was reading it to read your resume. Your resume should have the details, that describes you as an employee, highlighting your expertise.

The cover letter is often misunderstood and can be very useful if done correctly.
Your CV describes you and is (mostly) the same for all applications since you are the same person. The job description is the same for all candidates. The cover letter connects the two for this specific combination. It should contain

Assessment of the job requirements against your resume. Go through the requirements one by one and point to items on your resume to proof that you meet them. Its ok to not meet one or two.
Explain why the company is a good fit for you and your career plan (if you have one)
Explain why you are a good fit for the company (interests, culture, area of business, long term goals, etc.)

Item number 1 can be very useful when lots of applications are received. In many cases the first person to see your application is a low level HR staffer who may know little about the role. Their job is to simply do a rough requirements check and toss the obvious misfits and make the pile more manageable for the next screener. If you do this yourself, chances are it will be a lot more accurate and the HR staffer will love you for it.

@Hilamr, I appreciate your response. I do have a question which is the same that I asked above to keshlam, what are your thoughts regarding the STAR method when describing an experience. If the job is almost identical to what I have done, how should I go about this?

The star method is good for answering specific interview questions but it's IMO way to wordy for a resume.  Brevity is key, most resumes are read in 30s or less. For the cover letter, I would go through the list of job requirements 1 by 1 and reference the relevant section from your resume. Example "Experience in data analytics: I have 12 years combined experience through my role as XYZ and ABC and DEF at GHI".

First, repetition is not bad. The cover letter, the CV, and the interview serve different purposes and often involve different people. Having the same information on/in all three doesn't mean that a particular person will get it three times.
The purpose of the cover letter is to get them to read the CV. Nothing else. So "I have held a job that is almost identical to this one" is a great sentence for a cover letter. Yes, they could figure that out themselves if they read the CV, but the point of a cover letter is they haven't read the CV yet and you're trying to get them to do so.
Should you add more details about why you consider this job almost identical? Perhaps, if it's not obvious. I mean if you were "Assistant X of Y" at a large company, and you're applying to be "Assistant X of Y" in a similarly sized company in the same field, you probably don't need to. But if the job title doesn't make it obvious, or the cover-letter-reader might not recognize the company you held the previous job for, then sure, spell it out.
Cover letters generally summarize long CVs (20 years experience) and highlight incredibly relevant details (have held this same job already) and sometimes add relevant details (am moving to this city for personal reasons, have been a long time user of your product, have admired your founder since 2005, etc) that wouldn't be as relevant to another application for a different job.
When it comes time for an interview, although your CV got you the interview, the person interviewing you may not have been the one who chose you, and may not have read your CV recently if ever. Therefore you should never worry about repeating information that is on it. In fact a response like "well that's on my CV" would be very rude. Go ahead and tell them that you achieved X and led Y and managed Z and so on. I wouldn't use the rather formal language of a CV though, but would provide those facts in a more conversational way. This can include little side notes like "that was a really fun project" or "I enjoyed leading that initiative so much" which typically do not belong on a CV. In your case "I held this job at ABC for the last 4 years and enjoy doing it, so I would like to do it here too" is a fine answer to "what appeals to you about this job?" and the like.
You can also slide a reminder into your own questions. "At ABC we use System to manage [things]. Do you use that too?" Or "one of my major issues as a JobTitle was when [circumstance.] What do you have in place here to minimize that?" Be careful not to reveal internal details of your old job, of course, or to paint it as either a terrible mess or the best company that ever was (in case they worry you'll think they don't measure up.)

Others may disagree, but my expectation would be:
Focus the (brief!) cover letter on why you want to work for that company in specific and a very high level  summary of what overall skills/experience/enthusiasm you offer.
Focus the CV on documenting your acquisition and use of those skills.
The line is fuzzy, but I think of it as who you are and want to be vs. what you have done.

I appreciate your answer, I am a bit confused regarding the cover letter in a case like this because I have been taught to use the STAR method when describing an experience. So if the job is almost identical to what I have done, how should I go about this?

My approach is more SODAR/SAR, but it's roughly equivalent... However, that's more useful in the interview than in the paperwork, and more useful in the CV/resume than the cover letter, for the reasons I've given. The cover letter is just a teaser to get them interested in looking deeper at the resume and thinking about you as an individual.

What is SODAR/SAR/STAR?

@breversa: that should be a separate Question.
